# Efficiently populating a POJO with a large amount of getters and setters

Tags: java, refactoring, properties, getter-setter

I have a POJO which represents all the properties of my application. It contains a huge amount of Strings ints and booleans (class variables, and their getters/setters).

The problem is that every time a new property gets added, i have to add the variable, the getter, setter, the code that sets it from loading the property file and the code that uses the getter.

My Idea was to refactor this into a `getString(String stringToGet)`, `getInt` and `getBoolean` method that pulls from 3 hashmaps. The problem with doing it this way is that I can no longer use EL to get properties eg. `${Properties.telephoneNumber}`

Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: You should look into refactoring your POJO, maybe creating smaller POJOs with logically grouped properties. You may also want to look at http://projectlombok.org/ that will generate the getter/settes at runtime for you, keeping your code slicker.

Comment: JavaBeans require getters and setters. POJOs do not. I suspect you need a JavaBean for "EL" ;)

Comment: You should be able to use your IDE generate getter/setters so apart from cluttering your code, they shouldn't be much effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JSF 2.0 you can invoke methods with parameters in EL:

```
#{properties.getString('telephoneNumber')}
```

Comment: I like your answer. Is there a lot of work involved in adding JSF to a project?

Comment: That really depends on your project and how finished that project already is. Adding JSF to a small or new project is no effort at all. For starters, take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a class that you are absolutely sure you'll have get/set for every variable, I would just make the variables public. Usually the reason for not doing this is if it's possible you'll want to change the implementation or change variable names or something like that. If you KNOW it's not going to happen, I would go ahead and change the access to public.

Also, if you're using Eclipse (probably other IDEs, but I'm not familiar with them), it can automagically create get/set methods for you, so that shouldn't be a hassle.

I wouldn't use the solution you suggested. It would eliminate the convenience of auto-completion, which is especially needed when there are a lot of methods/variables.

Comment: I would recommend against this. It makes your code incredibly fragile. You should only every expose public member variables if the class is package-private and even then its debatable.

Comment: plus as many others have pointed out generating the getters/setters in eclipse/idea takes about 2 seconds

Comment: @nsfyn55 I also suggested this.

Comment: another issue is adding the code to call the setter and load the property. The other method just involves looping around all the properties and adding them to a hashmap, so individual code is not needed for each setter.

Answer (score 1):

Use your IDE to generate all those setters and getters.

Comment: Could you provide an example in a popular IDE to make this more constructive?